# How to count the no of records in gridview which have some particular data in a coloumn

Tags: asp.net, aspxgridview

How to count the no of records in Gridview which have some particular data in a column

```
 name        result
 ========    ======
 krishna     pass
 sanjay      pass    
 ajay        fail
```

out put needed in grid view - above Gridview already present,according to that grid i have to make another grid to count results

```
result   no 
======   =====
pass     2  
fail     1
```

Comment: How are you binding the first Gridview. Put that code in your question.

Comment: I would say go with **Linq** before bothering the initial **GridView** with heavy computing

Comment: Make 2 sql queries (if results are from DB), one for detail and other for aggregate. Bind grids accordingly.

Comment: that result coloumn is not actually coming from table. by datarowbound we are displaying that result

Comment: e.Row.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FF0000");
                    e.Row.Cells[6].Text = "Decreased";
                    decrs=decrs+1;

Comment: I said results (data) not result column. If data is coming from DB, then its better to do computations there

Answer (score 0):

in data row bound , i calculated

```
 protected void GVKeywordReport_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                DataRow pr = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row;
                int oldPos = Convert.ToInt32(pr["oldposition"]);
                int newPos = Convert.ToInt32(pr["newposition"]);
                GVKeywordReport.HeaderRow.Cells[3].Text = txtfrmdate.Text;
                GVKeywordReport.HeaderRow.Cells[4].Text = txtEndDate.Text;

                GVKeywordReport.HeaderRow.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#B3B300");
                e.Row.Cells[0].BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#B3B300");
                e.Row.Cells[5].BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFFFFF");

                if (oldPos == newPos)
                {
                    e.Row.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FF950E");
                    e.Row.Cells[6].Text = "No Change";
                   nc= nc+1;

                }
                else if (oldPos > newPos)
                {
                    e.Row.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFFFCC");
                    e.Row.Cells[6].Text = "Improved";
                   imprv= imprv+1;
                }
                else  

        {
            e.Row.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FF0000");
            e.Row.Cells[6].Text = "Decreased";
            decrs=decrs+1;
        }
       // e.Row.Cells[0].BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#7DA647");
    }
    txt_TargetReached.Text = "0";
    txtDecreased.Text =Convert.ToString(decrs);
```